# Shellcript to install OpenJDK and Apache Tomcat automatically in Ubuntu

Tags: shell, tomcat, ubuntu

I'm stucking when trying to install OpenJDK and Apache Tomcat in Ubuntu with the following script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y openjdk-6-jdk
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

When I executed this script, it didn't set environment for JAVA_HOME. Could you show me what problem occurred here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `source` the script in order to ensure that it runs in the *same* shell.

Execute your script by saying:

```
source ./myscript
```

or

```
. ./myscript
```

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> `. (a period)`
>
> ```
>       . filename [arguments]
> ```
>
> Read and execute commands from the filename argument in the current
>   shell context. ... This builtin is equivalent to `source`.